Exercise 7.6 of Robinson, Rodrigo, Sadowski: Smoothness of Navier-Stokes on Bounded Domains
My question is about Exercise 7.6 of the excellent book 'The Three-Dimensional Navier-Stokes Equations' by Robinson, Rodrigo and Sadowski. More generally, it is about higher regularity in space of solutions to the (let's say 2D) incompressible Navier-Stokes Equations on a bounded domain.
The set-up is that $u_n$ is the solution of the $n^{th}$ order Galerkin Approximation on a bounded domain with Dirichlet/no-slip boundary condition $u=0$ on the boundary. We are trying to achieve energy estimates of $u_n$ in higher order Sobolev Spaces. $P_n$ is the $n^{th}$ order projection onto the span of the first $n$ eigenfunctions of the associated Stokes Operator $A$. In the proof of the exercise, for $m=2k$, the step $$\Vert P_n(u_n \cdot \nabla)u_n\Vert_{H^{2k}} \leq c \Vert u_n \Vert_{H^m} \Vert \nabla u_n \Vert_{H^m} $$
occurs. I am assuming there is an intermediary step, $$\Vert P_n(u_n \cdot \nabla)u_n\Vert_{H^{2k}} \leq c\Vert (u_n \cdot \nabla)u_n\Vert_{H^{2k}}$$ for a constant $c$ independent of $n$, which is where my problem lies. From Lemma 4.1 of this book, we know that if $f \in D(A^{k})$ then $$\Vert P_nf \Vert_{H^{2k}} \leq c \Vert f \Vert_{H^{2k}}$$ which looks to be what is being used in the exercise. However I do not believe that $(u_n \cdot \nabla)u_n $ or $P(u_n \cdot \nabla)u_n$ for $P$ the Leray Projector belong to $D(A^k)$. Without $P$ it is not divergence-free, and with $P$ it is not of zero trace, so it cannot belong to this space. Therefore, my question is how is this step completed in the exercise? How is the $P_n$ controlled uniformly in these energy estimates?
I note that on the torus this is simple, as $P(u_n \cdot \nabla)u_n \in D(A^k)$. Many thanks!!
